# Receiving an Uncaught Type Error Cannot Read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to calculate the shipping costs based on purchase value and on two other variables (through radio buttons):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let fnum = 0,
      snum = 0;
    $('input[name="fnum"]').on("click", function() {
      fnum = parseFloat($('input[name="fnum"]:checked').val());

    });

    $('input[name="snum"]').on("click", function() {
      snum = parseFloat($('input[name="snum"]:checked').val());
    });

    let purchaseAmount = document.querySelector('#purchaseAmount');
    purchaseAmount.addEventListener('input', function() {
      valAsNumber = parseFloat(purchaseAmount.value);
    });

    $("button").on('click', function() {
      var boundaryValue1 = 24.99;
      var boundaryValue2 = 49.99;
      var shippingSubCost = 0;

      if (valAsNumber <= boundaryValue1) {
        shippingSubCost = 5.00;
      } else if (valAsNumber > boundaryValue1 && valAsNumber <= boundaryValue2) {
        shippingSubCost = 2.50;
      } else {
        shippingSubCost = 0.00;
      }


      var shippingCost = (shippingSubCost * fnum) + (valAsNumber * snum);
    });
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
    });

    var outputShippingCost = formatter.format(shippingCost);

    console.log("Shipping Cost = $" + outputShippingCost);
    console.log("Purchase Amount = $" + purchaseAmount);
    console.log("shippingSubFee = $" + shippingSubFee);
    console.log("preferredCustomer = " + preferredCustomer);
    console.log("trustedTraveler = " + trustedTraveler);

    $("#finalQuote").val(outputShippingCost);
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1003.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Get your Shipping Quote Now!</a>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main role="main" class="container" style="padding-top: 5em">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Enter Information</h1>

    <form id="addForm" name="addForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="card" style="">
          <div class="card-header">
            <b>Customer Information</b>
          </div>

          <div style="padding: 10px">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address">Address</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="province">Province</label>
                <select id="province" class="form-control" name="province">
                  <option value="ON" selected>ON</option>
                  <option value="NL">NL</option>
                  <option value="PE">PE</option>
                  <option value="NS">NS</option>
                  <option value="NB">NB</option>
                  <option value="QC">QC</option>
                  <option value="MB">MB</option>
                  <option value="SK">SK</option>
                  <option value="AB">AB</option>
                  <option value="BC">BC</option>
                  <option value="YT">YT</option>
                  <option value="NT">NT</option>
                  <option value="NU">NU</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="postalCode">Postal Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalCode" name="postalCode">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <b>Customer Purchasing Information</b>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div id="optionfood">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="preferredCustomer">Are you a Preferred Customer?</label>
                <input type="radio" id="preferredCustomer" name="fnum" value="0">Yes
                <input type="radio" id="preferredCustomer" name="fnum" value="1">No
                <br>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="trustedTraveler">Are you a Trusted Traveler?</label>
                <input type="radio" id="trustedTraveler" name="snum" value="0">Yes
                <input type="radio" id="trustedTraveler" name="snum" value="0.15">No
                <br>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="purchaseAmount">Purchase Amount ($CDN)</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="purchaseAmount" id="purchaseAmount" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$" value="" data-type="currency" placeholder="$0.00" min="0.01">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" onclick="AddQuote()" style="color: white">Submit</a>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
```

When I try to run this code, I receive an Uncaught Type Error Cannot Read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener').  Any ideas on why this is happening and how to recover from it?

I tried adjusting my HTML code but it didn't work

Comment: `document.querySelector()` will either return the element if it is found or `null` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you try to apply an event listener to the element whose tag name is `button`:

```
$("button").on(' /* your code */ ');
```

, and it doesn't work because there is no such element in your HTML. If you mean the element whose type is a button, you should write

```
$('[type="button"]').on(' /* your code */ ');
```

The main error seems to be at the end of the code, in the last line of the function. The command

```
$("#finalQuote").val(outputShippingCost);
```

should be inside the `[type="button"]` button function, but it's outside the function.

To fix the code, copy the command

```
$("#finalQuote").val(outputShippingCost);
```

and paste it into the function of the button `[type="button"]`. The correct code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let fnum = 0,
        snum = 0;
    $('input[name="fnum"]').on("click", function() {
        fnum = parseFloat($('input[name="fnum"]:checked').val());

    });

    $('input[name="snum"]').on("click", function() {
        snum = parseFloat($('input[name="snum"]:checked').val());
    });

    let purchaseAmount = document.querySelector('#purchaseAmount');
    purchaseAmount.addEventListener('input', function() {
        valAsNumber = parseFloat(purchaseAmount.value);
    });

    $('[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
        var boundaryValue1 = 24.99;
        var boundaryValue2 = 49.99;
        var shippingSubCost = 0;
        var valAsNumber = parseFloat(purchaseAmount.value);
        if (valAsNumber <= boundaryValue1) {
            shippingSubCost = 5.00;
        } else if (valAsNumber > boundaryValue1 && valAsNumber <= boundaryValue2) {
            shippingSubCost = 2.50;
        } else {
            shippingSubCost = 0.00;
        }
        var shippingCost = (shippingSubCost * fnum) + (valAsNumber * snum);

        const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
        });

        var outputShippingCost = formatter.format(shippingCost);

        console.log("Shipping Cost = $" + outputShippingCost);
        console.log("Purchase Amount = $" + purchaseAmount);
        console.log("shippingSubFee = $" + shippingSubFee);
        console.log("preferredCustomer = " + preferredCustomer);
        console.log("trustedTraveler = " + trustedTraveler);

        $("#finalQuote").val(outputShippingCost);
    });

});
```

Besides, the variable `shippingSubFee` is not defined.